# simple testing ViewResult and mocking Model used in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Inside controller I have view which returns simple object to the view.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

> how can I unit test this controller in order to check ViewResult,
>   basically to
>
> check if view is initialized? Basically how can I mock this MyModel
>   inside my unit test?

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
    {
        // controller is already set inside `SetUp` unit step.
        ViewResult res = this.controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(res);
    }
```

Update:

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
 {
      MyModel model = new MyModel();
      this.PopulatePageCombos(id);
      return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: `Assert.IsNotNull(res.Model as MyModel);` if your wanting to check the model has been passed to the view.

Comment: Do you need to check that the view is initialized? You're basically testing to see if the MVC engine is working instead of focusing on your own code. You can safely assume the View is there, that the model is passed. If you abstract your code and apply a proper SOC then you can test what you should be testing, which is your own functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The way you set this up, I presume you simply want to see if the model is not null:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
{
    ViewResult res = this.controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(res);
    var model = result.Model as MyModel;
    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```

Mocking would only make sense in a context where you'd get that model from an underlying interface, for example if you had:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
{
   MyModel model = _myModelQuerier.Fetch(id.Value);
   return View(model);
}
```

then you could get around something like

```
var modelQuerierMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyModelQuerier>();
modelQuerierMock.Stub(x => x.Fetch(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(new MyModel(2, "product"));
```

inside your test class

Comment: yours first solution works fine, I updated question with populating page combos, now test failes on that line. Should I post this as a new question?